# how to submit a form with action contains '#'

Tags: html, jsp

I have a form which action url contains character '#' (like 'xx/#xx/xxx.jsp). As the # is always treated as an HTML ANCHOR, the form actually submits to the URL 'xx/'. Anyone tell me how to make the form submit to the correct URL?

Comment: What do you mean with correct url? With included anchor?

Comment: How do you even expect this to work? How can your server even serve this URL?

Comment: Frankly said I am not sure how they did this, we are customizing an existing J2EE software. I believe there should be something like Filter/Title or something else...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Just replace `#` by `%23`, it works, I promise.

`%23` has the same meaning as `#` but without it's special behavior:

```
http://www.example.com/NameWithHash_%231/
```

will be decoded to

```
http://www.example.com/NameWithHash_#1/
```

on the sever.

Note, that you can address any ASCII character like this by using it's hex-code (`%<code>`). More examples: http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html